# HDMI with opensource drivers (radeon)

Tags: sound, ati, hdmi, alsa

My system (E45M1-I Deluxe with AMD onboard graphics with 4GB RAM) running Ubuntu 12.04. My problem is I have no HDMI sound if using the opensource drivers instead of fglrx.

I tried:

- to remove and purge all `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` packages and reinstalling alsa.
- resetting audio settings with `dpkg --configuration -a`
- adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"` to grub config
- enabling the device via `alsamixer`, although I only see S/PDIF instead of HDMI
- editing asound.conf with the card and device number

[I uploaded all sound based info via alsa-info here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d38f7b7b1e227342a6948600177f99c3c0e39a3c)

Are there recommended steps to go about installing HDMI sound?