# No sound through HDMI

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I noticed that I can't send sound to my television when I connect my laptop to my tv through hdmi.
I noticed that the hdmi is recognised, but I can't select it.
I tried setting a profile to it, by using "Pulseaudio volume control" but no luck(image at the bottom of the post).

Here is the output from `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The device is an acer aspire 7750G with specs:

- AMD Radeon™ HD 6650M
- i7-2630M

I am using this driver:

[image: The driver]

So what am I to do next?

Thanks in advance.

[image: No luck]

Comment: Are you using the radeon driver or the proprietary ones?

Comment: O ofcourse, I am using the 'x.org X server' drivers, because proprietary and amd drivers both don't work(glitch out my screen or do not give a screen at all).

Comment: Duplicate question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/329510/hdmi-with-opensource-drivers-radeon (I have same set up but I cannot get it to work properly, I get sound but not surround sound with either proprietary or default radeon drivers :(

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins That question was never answered, is about a different card and a different Ubuntu version. Thanks for looking though.

Comment: @Rinzwind That is the window you see on the left in the screenshot.
If you can tell me what I have to do different, please tell me.
Thanks for responding.

Comment: ah I missed that. one second.1 sec later: I have exactly the same info there. even the device driver! and hdmi works for me :) make sure "output" has hdmi too ;) did you check `alsamixer` settings?

Comment: Pardon me, but why is this tagged `13.04`?

Comment: @Blue-ManedHawk The question is 6 years old... Dr. Brunsen: I know sometimes a patient spends a lot of time in OR, but can this one be killed and taken off the slab?

Comment: Ohhhh.  Well, that makes sense, @WinEunuuchs2Unix.

Answer (score 0):

To activate HDMI audio while using the open-source drivers edit the /boot/grub/menu.lst file and add this to the end of your "kernel" line:

radeon.audio=1

Also in terminal type this following command to update grub:

sudo update-grub

Comment: I found that I am using grub2, which uses grub.cfg. At which line? My uname -r gives back 3.8.29, but there are 3 lines that match with that given kernel name.